# Listing JSON fields in Python

Tags: python, json

This is my first go at using JSON in Python.

For example, say that I had a JSON file that lists employees first and last names.

How would I go about listing the first names of all the employees?

I can get it to display the first name for one person:

```
import json

json_data = open('app.json')
data = json.load(json_data)

print data['employees'][0]['firstname']
```

So I then tried two ways to list all the first names, both error:

```
print data['employees']['firstname']
print data['employees'][0:]['firstname']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to extract all the first names:

```
print [emp['firstname'] for emp in data['employees']]
```

or use an explicit loop, printing each name separately:

```
for emp in data['employees']:
    print emp['firstname']
```